# How to invoke a parallel process from a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet and I need to invoke a parallel process from this.

That process will do a prolonged query and send a email with result when finished.

The role of servlet is only start this process and return to client, how I can do this?

I tried to use a thread inside the servlet, but this is not a good practice in JEE.

Comment: That's called as a `Thread`, why it is not good practise ? Servlet it self is a thread.

Comment: Because if the thread is too longer, when the process is finished and returned to servlet, it does not exists anymore. Unless I call a method void that is the last thread of executable line, this would solve?

Comment: You just create a thread and leave it running and get back to servlet.